# Avoid page range compression with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am using `biblatex` for my bibliography and i would like it *not* to compress page ranges at all. Can this by done with a simple argument?

```
\usepackage[url=false,sorting=none,firstinits=true,isbn=false,arxiv=abs,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{user}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{library.bib}
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{mylibrary.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearfield{day}
  \clearfield{month}
  \clearfield{endday}
  \clearfield{endmonth}
  \clearfield{issue}
  \clearfield{number}
}

%i tried this, to avoid the execution of \mkcomprange but it doesn't help
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}

\begin{document}
```

here are two bibtex entries

```
    @article{Perdew1992,
annote = {PW91},
author = {Perdew, J.P. and Wang, Y.},
issn = {1550-235X},
journal = {Physical Review B},
number = {23},
pages = {13244--13249},
publisher = {APS},
title = {{Accurate and simple analytic representation of the electron-gas correlation energy}},
url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.45.13244},
volume = {45},
year = {1992}
}

@article{Delley2006,
author = {Delley, Bernard},
doi = {10.1021/jp0653611},
issn = {1089-5639},
journal = {The journal of physical chemistry. A},
month = dec,
number = {50},
pages = {13632--9},
pmid = {17165892},
title = {{Ground-state enthalpies: evaluation of electronic structure approaches with emphasis on the density functional method.}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17165892},
volume = {110},
year = {2006}
}
```

where the first one appears as

> [23] J. P. Perdew and Y. Wang. “Accurate and simple analytic
>   representation of the electron-gas correlation energy”. In: Physical
>   Review B 45 (1992), pp. 13244–13249. doi: 10.1103/PhysRevB.45.13244.

with full page range and the second one appears as

> [26] B. Delley. “Ground-state enthalpies: evaluation of electronic
>   structure approaches with emphasis on the density functional method.”
>   In: The journal of physical chemistry. A 110 (2006), pp. 13632–9. doi:
>   10.1021/jp0653611.

with the page range compression I want to avoid.

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Comment: This is not really a minimal example. Could you include some examples that illustrate the behaviour you want to avoid, and show how you would _like_ the output to appear instead...

Comment: yes, of course. I included two entries that actually appear different in the output. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex` is able to compress page ranges as well as to leave intact the page ranges as included in your `.bib` file. However (at least as far as I know), it is not possible by default to "un-compress" page ranges that are included in a `.bib` file in abbreviated form.

Comment: :-) sometimes a different pair of eyes will see the obvious

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}`which is the default setup and the one you use should actually do the trick. But since it doesn't in your case, we do indeed need a minimal example to see what's going on.

Comment: yes, of course. I included two entries that actually appear different in the output. thanks!

Comment: That's still no working minimal example.